# Custom Gitlab CI Runner in Kubernetes can't connect to gitlab.com docker repo

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I wanted to build docker images and save them into the gitlab.com docker registry. This works perfectly if the docker build runs in a runner from gitlab.com, but it doesn't if I want to run it in my owner runner, that is connected to gitlab.com. I deployed it with `privileged:true` to AKS and other builds are working.

When I want to do docker login, I got the following error:
`x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Any idea?

Comment: What do you use to run the runner?

Comment: Your error insinuates that the certificate store you're runner is using doesn't trust the root CA of registry.gitlab.com (which is the URL for the gitlab docker registry). You should likely try remoting into one of the Azure compute servers and determine if there is a root CA issue on the server itself. You may also have to update ca_cert setting in your gitlab runner advanced config.